# nm-applet Kali Linux Raspberry Pi dropdown non-responsive

Tags: networking, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, networkmanager, gtk

Alright, after updating (`sudo apt-get update,upgrade, dist-upgrade`) to Kali linux armhf kernel 4.1.19-v7 on a raspberry pi model 3B, my nm-aplet sysicon has stopped responding.It is visible on the panel, but I cannot click on it to produce the drop-down menu.

When I run sudo nm-applet from terminal I get the following errors upon clicking on the new icon:

```
(nm-applet:4226): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to underallocate toplevel GtkTrayIcon 0x4f2370. Allocation is 22x22, but minimum required size is 24x24.

*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
```

***what on earth can I do to fix this***? I am currently using `wicd` but it has no vpn support which is annoying. Do I need to find code somewhere with an instance of `pixman_region32_init_rect()` and fux with it myself? Am I missing something?

my kernel is 4.1.19-v7, armhf.

Thanks all who can shed light on this!

Answer (score 1):

You don't run nm-applet as root (sudo). nm-applet is a client for NetworkManager, that communicates via D-Bys with the demon. If it needs to elevate privileges, NetworkManager asks PolicyKit to authenticate the request. I could imagine that it can cause problems to run it as root, it is anyway something you do not want to do.

If it still doesn't work, it sounds like a bug. I would report that downstream against your distribution.

If nm-applet doesn't work, you can also use one of the other clients, like nmcli or nmtui (I guess you are not using Gnome3 or KDE, otherwise there is also gnome-shell and plama-nm).

Comment: Alright,  thanks. I understand it should not be run as root,  but it gives terminal output that may be helpful. I usually let it run normally otherwise